# FFMPEG Concat only showing first video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I;m struggling with concat

My command (via Process Builder)

> [ffmpeg, -y, -i,
>   C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -i, C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4,
>   -filter_complex, [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][4:a:0][5:v:0][5:a:0][6:v:0][6:a:0][7:v:0][7:a:0][8:v:0][8:a:0][9:v:0][9:a:0][10:v:0][10:a:0]concat=n=11:v=1:a=1
>   [v][a], -map, [v], -map, [a],
>   C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8d66984a-0b0e-4956-95d6-66eddf14b47e.mp4]

And the above error repeats over and over again. The video completes and it is the right size and duration, it just plays the first video and then stops.

Any clues!?

EDIT With latest version

```
   ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #5:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #6:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #6:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #7:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #7:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #8:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #8:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #9:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #9:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #10, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18134 kb/s
    Stream #10:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x1920, 17995 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #10:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat:in2:v0
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat:in3:v0
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> concat:in3:a0
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> concat:in4:v0
  Stream #4:1 (aac) -> concat:in4:a0
  Stream #5:0 (h264) -> concat:in5:v0
  Stream #5:1 (aac) -> concat:in5:a0
  Stream #6:0 (h264) -> concat:in6:v0
  Stream #6:1 (aac) -> concat:in6:a0
  Stream #7:0 (h264) -> concat:in7:v0
  Stream #7:1 (aac) -> concat:in7:a0
  Stream #8:0 (h264) -> concat:in8:v0
  Stream #8:1 (aac) -> concat:in8:a0
  Stream #9:0 (h264) -> concat:in9:v0
  Stream #9:1 (aac) -> concat:in9:a0
  Stream #10:0 (h264) -> concat:in10:v0
  Stream #10:1 (aac) -> concat:in10:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] profile High, level 5.1
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\workspace\processor\.\temp_dir\30965932-c67a-4948-984c-613b2f06ce04.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x1920, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
video:148240kB audio:1120kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.035871%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] mb I  I16..4: 31.1% 40.5% 28.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] mb P  I16..4: 12.2% 19.8%  4.0%  P16..4: 35.5%  9.9%  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:15.6%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] mb B  I16..4:  2.4%  2.6%  0.6%  B16..8: 42.0%  4.6%  0.4%  direct: 1.4%  skip:45.9%  L0:46.3% L1:49.4% BI: 4.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] 8x8 transform intra:53.4% inter:73.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.9% 31.9% 4.6% inter: 12.0% 14.0% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 41% 11% 23%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 31% 27%  2%  2%  2%  4%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 32% 14%  2%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 54% 23% 18%  4%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] ref P L0: 65.3% 17.7% 13.9%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] ref B L0: 90.7%  9.0%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] ref B L1: 99.6%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000287d1c0] kb/s:17249.64
[aac @ 000000000287b000] Qavg: 1577.720
```

Comment: Get a recent dated static build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ and check.

Comment: Hi that is using the most recent 64 bit built.

Comment: No, it's using `ffmpeg version 2.8.4` which is from Dec 2015.

Comment: Thanks. Strange. I have the path variable set to program files/ffmpeg/bin - when I run ffmpeg outside of this folder I get the old version, when I run it inside this folder I get the new version. It's getting picked up from somewhere else. T

Comment: Thanks it's doing the same thing but no errors.

Comment: @Mulvya If you want to add as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: Does the output play fine?

Comment: No but there was some errors I could use, so I could fix it (one of the videos wasn't the same dimensions as the others).  I'd installed some other software that had FFMPEG bundled which was being picked up first in the command line.

Comment: use `ffmpeg -i C:\workspace\processor.\temp_dir\8fdcc1c9-6275-4ef5-b9e7-05bd5cfe51ab_3840.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]hstack=12" -c:a copy out.mp4`